# Parsing a CSV HTML stream in R

Tags: html, r, html-parsing, web-scraping

I am trying to parse an html page that is displayed in csv format.

I would like to read this table on the fly of the page directly into R (http://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/esp/esp2csv.cgi?id=slkw1) and then convert the data into a matrix for further crunching.

Not sure if RCurl or XML packages are the best way to do it but have not been able to find a good way to parse the object once I get it into R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this far. If someone can go further, please edit my answer.

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
# grab the content. can't use readHTMLTable since this isn't one.
htmldata <- getURL('http://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/esp/esp2csv.cgi?id=slkw1')
# grab data between the pre tags
dataonly <- substr(htmldata, str_locate(data, "<pre>")[2]+1 ,
str_locate(data, "</pre>")[1]-1)
# replace <br> tags with new lines.
dataonly2 <- str_replace(dataonly, "<br />", "\n")
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for this, I think it was close to working and then the script above came in and I ended up playing with that for a half-hour.  Thank you though!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
> con=url("http://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/esp/esp2csv.cgi?id=slkw1")
> table(count.fields(con, sep=","))

    1 25521 
    2     1
```

So there are two lines with one field only ... turns out that skipping two lines lets the data read succeed.

```
> con=url("http://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/esp/esp2csv.cgi?id=slkw1")
> temp <- scan(file=con,  skip=2, what="a", sep=",") 
# paged through the scan results
> table(grepl("<br />", temp))

FALSE  TRUE 
25478    43

> con=url("http://www.nwrfc.noaa.gov/esp/esp2csv.cgi?id=slkw1")
> temp <- readLines(con=con)
> temp2=gsub("<br />", "\n", temp)
# Knew that the first two lines were HTML junk.
> temp3 = read.table( text=temp2[3], sep= ",", fill =TRUE, header=TRUE)
> str(temp3)
'data.frame':   43 obs. of  581 variables:
 $ X.pre.STA.ID: Factor w/ 1 level "SLKW1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ START.YEAR  : int  1949 1950 1951 1952 1953 1954 1955 1956 1957 1958 ...
 $ X9.1        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
 $ X9.2        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
 $ X9.3        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
 $ X9.4        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
 $ X9.5        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...
 $ X9.6        : int  -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 -999 ...

snipped  output  There is better data below

 $ X9.18       : int  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 ...
 $ X9.19       : int  41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 41 ...
 $ X9.20       : int  40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 40 ...
 $ X9.21       : int  39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 ...
 $ X9.22       : int  39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 ...
 $ X9.23       : int  39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 39 ...
 $ X9.24       : int  38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 ...
 $ X9.25       : int  38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 ...
 $ X9.26       : int  38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 ...
 $ X9.27       : int  38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 38 ...
 $ X9.28       : int  48 53 106 49 89 48 94 117 49 49 ...
 $ X9.29       : int  57 45 436 40 403 38 145 294 40 40 ...
 $ X9.30       : int  259 34 1270 37 1622 33 80 432 37 37 ...
```

The last column gets coerced to either factor or character depenging on the read.table setting because the last element in the last line is

```
>  temp3[43, 581]
[1] "-999</pre></body>"
```

Several ways of handling that. Pick one. Doesn't really matter much since the entire column is -999 anyway.

Comment: Thanks! This works well, I will make a few modifications to massage the data but this stripped out all of the unwanted html tags.  One question is how does this: "read.table( text=temp2[3], sep= ",", fill =TRUE, header=TRUE)" remove the <pre> tag at the beginning of the html stream?  I tried using gsub to replace all the <pre> and <body> tags prior to using that line and the thing blew up.  Thanks again!

Comment: The <pre> and <body> tags are temp2[1:2] and I only passed temp2[3] to `read.table()`.